# IList<IClient> method<T>() where T : Iclient can not add client object to list

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-method

public IList GetClientsByListofID(IList ids) where T : IClient
    {
        IList clients = new List();
        clients.Add( new Client(3));
    }

I am getting a compiler error here:

**cannot convert from 'Bailey.Objects.Client' to 'T'**

The client object implements the IClient interface.  My goal here is to try and loosen the coupling between my classes (learning DI stuff atm).  I was thinking that I can say it can use any type of client object and that would be returned.

Am I completely off base here?

Thanks

Jon Hawkins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use generic constraints in this way.  How can the compiler guarantee that the type parameter is a `Client` simply because it implements the `IClient` interface?  Couldn't many types implement that interface?

In this case (*that is in the case where you need to work with the type, not the interface*) it is better to constrain the type parameter with the type itself like this:

```
public IList<T> GetClientsByListofID<T>(IList<int> ids) where T : Client
{
    IList<T> clients = new List<T>();
    clients.Add(new Client(3));
    // ...
}
```

and once doing that I am wondering if you need a generic method at all:

```
public IList<Client> GetClientsByListofID(IList<int> ids)
{
    IList<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
    clients.Add(new Client(3));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Good point. Another solution would be to have the method return IList<IClient> instead of IList<T>.

Comment: maybe I am misunderstanding but I thought that if it did implement that interface it could be returned as an IClient and not worry about its actual class.  I think I got my knickers in a twist and realized that in this problem generics was not needed, (ur second solution works perfectly).  Thank you

Comment: this would still result in a compile error, unfortunately.  This is due to the way the declaration of the List does NOT match the .Add statement on the line below.  You can't add a concrete type to an open typed list.  That's why you're getting the compile error.

Answer (score 1):

`Client` is a `IClient`.
`T` is a `IClient`.

Where did you specify that `T` is a `Client`? Nowhere!

I think you need a `IClientFactory` or `IClientRepository` that will create/retrieve IClient instances for you. You will then be able to use different implementations of this factory/repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public interface IClient
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Client : IClient
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

     ...

public IList<T> GetClientsByListofID<T>( IList<int> ids )
         where T : class, IClient
{
    var clients = new List<T>();
    var client = new Client { Name = "bob" } as T;

    clients.Add( client );

    return clients;
}
```

Usage:

```
     var clients = this.GetClientsByListOfID<Client>( null );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in the constraint

```
where T : IClient
```

but rather in the use of your List.

You can't say this:

```
IList<T> clients = new List<T>();
clients.Add( new Client(3));
```

you CAN say this: (this assumes your constraint includes "new")

```
IList<T> clients = new List<T>();
clients.Add( new T());
```

in this case your constraint would then need to be:

```
    where T : new(), IClient
```

or you could do this but it wouldn't use generics at all:

```
IList<T> clients = new List<Client>();
clients.Add( new Client(3));
```

The reason why you can't do what you're trying to do is because the compiler can't gaurantee that the type T will be of type Client, which is why it's giving you the compiler error.  It doesn't have anything to do with your constraint really.

Answer (score 0):

What your are doing doesn't work because in C# 3.0 generics don't support covariance.

You could do something like this:

```
    interface IClient
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class Client : IClient
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Client() { }
    }

    // ...

    public IList<T> GetClientsByListofID<T>(IList<int> ids) where T : IClient, new()
    {
        IList<T> clients = new List<T>();
        clients.Add(new T() { Id = 3 });
        // ...
        return clients;
    }
```

... but I wonder if you need generics at all.